# php5 not working with nginx 1.9.3

Tags: nginx, web-server, php5

I am new to nginx, and having some trouble with php5. 
(I had it sorta working, but cant seem to get it working again.)
There are 2 files I am woring with, that seem to control nginx, and php5-fpm.
/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

From the php5 www.conf file:

```
;listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

from the nginx conf file:

```
#  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

when both are set to 127.0.0.1:9000 php pages load blank pages, and this error in

```
/var/log/nginx/error.log
2015/09/05 09:06:29 [error] 20085#20085: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: <ip>, server: , request: "GET /server.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "address"
```

when both are set to /var/run/php5-fpm.sock webpages display "Bad gateway", and this error in

```
    /var/log/nginx/error.log  
: <ip>, server: , request: "GET /server.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "address"
2015/09/05 09:07:14 [crit] 20189#20189: *3 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client
```

php had been working, with the exception that it was only *.php files loaded, where php tags were broken, when inside htm/html files. Now all of it is busted. like an idiot, I did not back up my original config files. Can someone help me get php5 working?
This is a debian, jessie server. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Both messages indicate that php-fpm isn't *actually* listening on the configured port.  Perhaps you need to restart the php-fpm master?